# Join table very slow how can I fix it?

Tags: mysql

I have problem with my query because of joining a lot of table.   So I would like to find another ways beside this query but the result it the same. My code is bellow :

```
SELECT 
    tblReturn.CountryID, 
    tblReturn.ShopLocationId, 
    tblReturn.ReturnID, 
    tblVoucherDetail.VoucherDetailID,
    tblVoucherDetail.VoucherNo,
    tblVoucherDetail.BarcodeVoucher, 
    tblReturn.DateTimeStamp AS DateTimeReturn,
    tblClient.ClientNoString, 
    tblSaleDetail.BarCode, 
    tblReturnType.Description, 
    tblReturn.Reason, 
    tblSale.DateTimeStamp AS DateTimeSale,tblReturn.Status 
FROM 
(
    tblSale 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        (
            (
                tblReturn 
                INNER JOIN 
                (
                     tblVoucherDetail 
                     INNER JOIN
                     tblVoucher ON tblVoucherDetail.VoucherID = tblVoucher.VoucherID
                ) ON tblReturn.ReturnID = tblVoucher.ReturnID
            ) 
            INNER JOIN 
                 tblClient 
            ON 
                 tblVoucherDetail.ClientNo = tblClient.ClientNo
        ) 
        INNER JOIN 
            tblSaleDetail 
        ON 
            tblReturn.SaleDetailIDOrigin = tblSaleDetail.SaleDetailID) 
        ON 
            (tblSale.SaleID = tblSaleDetail.SaleID) 
        AND 
            (tblSale.ShopLocationID = tblSaleDetail.ShopLocationID)) 
        INNER JOIN 
            tblReturnType 
        ON 
            tblReturn.ReturnTypeID = tblReturnType.ReturnTypeID
        WHERE 
            tblReturn.CountryID = 7 
        AND  
            tblReturn.ShopLocationID = 4   
       ORDER BY 
            tblVoucherDetail.VoucherDetailID DESC
```

How can I adjust it?

Comment: I would suggest some how formatting the query

Comment: It was very slow so I would like to change query or something but still keep the same result. Furthermore, this query I toke from my supervisor. So I difficult to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Use explain and indexes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html. Using indexes will enable the database to optimize the search

Answer (score 0):

While optimizing your query is good (indexes are your friend), there is another approach you might consider with this many joins.  "Denormalize" your database and create a table that has exactly the data you want.  This involves updating your data both in the original table and in the new "report" table you create.  There are obvious disadvantages to this -- (1) more space used, (2) you have to either write code to keep your data in sync, or you have to rebuild your "report" table on a periodic basis, (3) subtle bugs can happen if you data *does* get out of sync.

However, sometimes denormalizing is the simplest and best solution to nasty join performance problems.